# Grouped Table View Obj-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I followed the tutorial [here](http://gigaom.com/apple/iphone-dev-sessions-create-a-navigation-based-application/) and was wondering how to make the table appear grouped.

ex:

group1 contains Subview One and Subview Two

group2 contains Subview Three

I switched the type in interface builder but that only shows one group.

Thanks,
Adam

Sidenote* I am a completely new at objective c, hence the tutorial.

**EDIT**

I thought it might be helpful to put up the piece of code

```
#import "RootViewController.h"
#import "SubViewOneController.h"
#import "SubViewTwoController.h"


@implementation RootViewController


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark View lifecycle

-(void)awakeFromNib {
    views = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

SubViewOneController *subViewOneController = [[SubViewOneController alloc] init];
SubViewTwoController *subViewTwoController = [[SubViewTwoController alloc] init];

//Subview 1

    subViewOneController.title = @"Subview One";
    [views addObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                      @"Subview One",           @"title",
                      subViewOneController,     @"controller",
                      nil]];
    [subViewOneController release];

//Subview 2

subViewOneController = [[SubViewOneController alloc] init];
subViewOneController.title = @"Subview Two";
[views addObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                  @"Subview Two",           @"title",
                  subViewTwoController,     @"controller",
                  nil]];
[subViewOneController release];

//Subview 3

subViewOneController = [[SubViewOneController alloc] init];
subViewOneController.title = @"Subview Three";
[views addObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                  @"Subview Three",         @"title",
                  subViewOneController,     @"controller",
                  nil]];
[subViewOneController release];

UIBarButtonItem *temporaryBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] init];
temporaryBarButtonItem.title = @"Back";
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = temporaryBarButtonItem;
[temporaryBarButtonItem release];

self.title = @"Basic Navigation";
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
return 2;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
return [views count];
}
//
//I think it goes somewhere in here
//
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

cell.text = [[views objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"title"];


return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
UIViewController *targetViewController = [[views objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"controller"];
[[self navigationController] pushViewController:targetViewController animated:YES];
}

- (void)dealloc {
[views dealloc];
[super dealloc];
}


@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so you are correct it does go into your cellForRowAtIndexPath: you will be looking to do something like:

if ([indexPath section] == 0) {
  //stuff for first section.
}

if ([indexPath section] == 1) {
  //stuff for second section.
}

You will need to also deal with how your are configuring the cell from your array. The sections row numbers start with 0. The same thing with didSelectRowAtIndexPath:
If you don't deal with the section where you set the cell.text you will end up with

Subview One

Subview Two

Subview One

I recommend getting the [iPhone Programming (The Big Nerd Ranch Guide)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321706242)

Answer (score 1):

In Interface Builder, choose your UITableView object and choose Grouped as the style.

If you are programmatically creating it, use the `initWithStyle:` [**`UITableViewStyleGrouped`**](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html%23//apple_ref/c/econst/UITableViewStyleGrouped).

**EDIT:**

```
if (section == 0) { /* your first section */ }

if (section == 1) { /* your second section */ }
```

Comment: I have already set it in interface builder. my problem is that I dont know how to tell each view that I add which group to be in.

Comment: Where would I impliment that? I put it in my root view controller but it says that "section" is undeclared. Please tell me if I am missing something completely obvious.

Comment: You obviously need to read some of the Apple docs. The code I provided would go in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` delegate emthod.

Comment: Please excuse my stupidity, but if you could tell me what to do with this. I have posted my code and left where I think it should go near in a comment. I am probably dead wrong, but I thought I would try.

Answer (score 1):

This is all controlled by your UITableViewDataSource. The `numberOfSectionsInTableView:` method controls how many groups there are, and `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` controls how many rows are in each group.

Your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` on the UITableViewDelegate gets an NSIndexPath object; `indexPath.section` tells you which group and `indexPath.row` tells you which row in the group. The cell you return really has no idea which group it is in or which row in the group it is, it's all controlled by the fact that you return it for a particular indexPath when `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` is called.